# Add Id for each annotation in MapKit

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I need to add an Id for each annotation in map to open new view controller by clicking on info button in annotation , my problem is in prepare and perform segue, I created it, but I don't know how to pass the id to the segue.

I created sub class for annotation to store the ID that comes from JSON

Thats parts of my code :

Getting all data from JSON :

```
for location in self.locations {

  let annotation:MyAnnotation = MyAnnotation()
  annotation.title = location["truck_name"] as? String
  annotation.customTruckId = location["truck_id"] as? String
  annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location["coor_x"] as! NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (location["coor_y"] as! NSString).doubleValue)
  self.AllMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

  }
```

Sub class I created:

```
class MyAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var customTruckId : String?
}
```

Problem is here in segue :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowTruckFromMap") {

            let des_VC = segue.destination as! TruckDetailsVC

            des_VC.truck_id = "How to get Id here !"
        }
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowTruckFromMap", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can show your UIViewController without using Segue.
You must at first put an identifier to your UIViewController in :
identity Inspector -> Identity -> storyboard ID = TruckDetailsVCIdentifier

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
           let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let desController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TruckDetailsVCIdentifier") as! TruckDetailsVC
           let TruckAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation
           desController.truck_id = (TruckAnnotation?.customTruckId!)!
           show(desController, sender: self)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is how to get the `truck_id` and pass it to annotation

Answer (score 1):

I found Answer:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let desController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TruckDetailsVC") as! TruckDetailsVC

            let TruckAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation

            desController.truck_id = (TruckAnnotation?.customTruckId!)!

            show(desController, sender: self)

        }
    }
```

Thanks for all

Comment: it's what i told you in my answer !

Comment: My problem was how to get the id dynamically in segue or in other method, I also do it with segue, thanks for your help